# Is there a step-by-step solution for implement voip into iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, voip, wifi

I want to develop voip application for that how to I start up application.
provide me steps how to achieve this and there is a third party available for that.

Comment: I very much doubt there's a "step-by-step" guide to creating a VoIP app for iOS - it's almost like you have to do some research and actual work yourself to create such an application, bizarre though that may seem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [MiuMiu](https://github.com/pzion/miumiu/wiki), a VoIP app for iOS. It uses [Asterisk](http://www.asterisk.org/) for the server.